# advertisement won't center in ie unless body is text-align:center

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, centering

I have an advertisement that loads a script, and its inside a centered div. 
No matter what I do ie6, ie7, and ie8 won't center it unless body has

```
text-align:center;
```

Right now the css for the div is set like this, which works only on chrome/firefox:

```
#header{
    width:730px;
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:center;}
```

I tried using .getScript with a chain like this:

```
.css('text-align', 'center');
```

But the script won't load externally in chrome and it then sets the CSS for the entire page to the width of the script. I also tried putting it in an html page and loading that with jquery inside of a centered div, but it just sits on the left side of the page.

I also tried waiting till $(document).ready and then centering the div, but that didn't work either.

The main problem is all of the text in the page isn't wrapped by any other div where I can align the text left, and this is being applied to about 1000+ web pages.

Comment: Could you add some HTML? What's the problem? Your `<div>` is not centered on your page? If so, add `margin: auto;` to the CSS of that div.

Comment: edited. I can get more specific if you want, but there really isn't much html code to it.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: is there nothing wrapping the content other than ?  If not, just text-align center on the body, use margin 0 auto on the ad div as Jules suggested, and text-align left on the content.  If your DOM is lacking anything around the content, you may have to live with a compromise.

Comment: Right, I understand if I have a div around the content I can text-align left that div, but as I said there's 1000+ html pages all with different layouts that don't currently have one. I'm thinking a perl script to ad in a div is my only option at this point.

Comment: Sorry, sounds like adding a div is your only choice.  Good luck!